# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ," using google maps api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

im using google maps javascript api. on load in calling the initialize method as said in the api, but i keep getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ," error but could not find the source why im getting this error.

Please Help. Thanks in advance

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
            function initialize() {
              var mapOptions = {
                  zoom: 4,
                 center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922)
               };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('geochart-view-wrapper'),
  mapOptions);

       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: map.getCenter(),
          map: map,
           title: 'Click to zoom'
          });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
// 3 seconds after the center of the map has changed, pan back to the
// marker.
window.setTimeout(function() {
  map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
     }, 3000);
 });

     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     map.setZoom(8);
      map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    });
 }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);

    </script> `
```

Comment: Does it throw a line number in the error?

Comment: no it does not give any line number.

Comment: well, on the last line, after the script end tag, you have a extra symbol.

Comment: no that is added while posting the question but not in my script. i changed the api and i don't get  that error anymore. but im not able to see the map ,nor i get any error .

Answer (score 0):

I ran the script through JSHint:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922)
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('geochart-view-wrapper'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: map.getCenter(),
        map: map,
        title: 'Click to zoom'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function () {
        // 3 seconds after the center of the map has changed, pan back to the
        // marker.
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
        }, 3000);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        map.setZoom(8);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

This is now syntax-error-free. My guess is that the lines that had

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('geochart-view-wrapper'),
mapOptions);
```

were causing it.

By the way, formatting your code will make it easier to identify logic errors, syntax errors, closure errors, etc.

Comment: thank you. I fixed those errors. But now im getting the map but it is not visible.. if it inspect the div i can see that it is filled with the map. but.i cant have a view of it. Does this div that we insert the map should be independent or can be child to any other tag  like section or article in html.